# How to use the hashimoto light algorithm in pyethash?

Tags: python, pyethereum, ethash

I have a problem with using the hashimoto light algorithm in pyethash.

I am using pyethash version 23.1 and comparing the results with ethash.run (ethashjs 0.0.7).

Using the same inputs the result should be the same but I am getting different outputs on OSX 10.10.

#### pyethash:

```
import pyethash

blocknr = 229
headerHash = "123deb946d8dd98c79b527d3da0a19210a7193fd6a9c1f496b2c26c9ca4a7933"
nonceStr = "a8c2231491f43da2"

cacheSize = pyethash.get_cache_size(blocknr)
seed = pyethash.get_seedhash(blocknr)

cache = pyethash.mkcache_bytes(
        cacheSize,
        seed).encode('hex')

nonce = long(nonceStr, 16)
fullSize = pyethash.get_full_size(blocknr)

light_result = pyethash.hashimoto_light(fullSize, cache, headerHash.decode("hex"), nonce)
print "result: " + ''.join(x.encode('hex') for x in light_result['result'])
```

#### ethashjs:

```js
const Ethash = require('ethashjs');
const levelup = require('levelup');
const memdown = require('memdown');
const BN = require('bn.js');

var block = 229;
var headerHash="123deb946d8dd98c79b527d3da0a19210a7193fd6a9c1f496b2c26c9ca4a7933"
var nonce="a8c2231491f43da2"

var cacheDB = levelup('', {
    db: memdown
});
var ethash = new Ethash(cacheDB);

ethash.loadEpoc(block, function(){

    var result = ethash.run(new Buffer(headerHash, 'hex'), new Buffer(nonce, 'hex'));
    console.log("result " + (new BN(result.hash)).toString(16));

});
```

The implementation in ethashjs should be correct (it was used to validate a hash for mining a block in my test net). Maybe somebody got a pointer for me!

Answer (score 0):

I might have come across something that should be of help. ~6 years later though :/

This [segment](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/master/ethereum/ethpow.py#L27), more specifically this [line](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/master/ethereum/ethpow.py#L31) suggest some endianness conversion is going on with the nonce.

```py
if ETHASH_LIB == 'ethash':
    mkcache = ethash.mkcache
    EPOCH_LENGTH = ethash_utils.EPOCH_LENGTH
    hashimoto_light = ethash.hashimoto_light
elif ETHASH_LIB == 'pyethash':
    mkcache = pyethash.mkcache_bytes
    EPOCH_LENGTH = pyethash.EPOCH_LENGTH
    hashimoto_light = lambda s, c, h, n: \
        pyethash.hashimoto_light(s, c, h, utils.big_endian_to_int(n))
```

So perhaps you had to convert the nonce to int from big endian format?